# Проблема обмена 1С с сайтом

Tags: php, opencart, 1с

Есть интернет магазин на openCart и база 1С.
Проблема состоит в следующем - есть база 1С примерно 12к наименований, в настройках выгрузки установлено количество товара больше 0, т.е. только что есть на складе, в итоге одновременно загружает порядка 5.5к товара.
База настроена таким образом что перед выгрузкой новой базы старая база удаляется (это связано со спецификой деятельности). Иногда, через раз возникает подобная ошибка:

Произошла ошибка на стороне сервера.
Обмен не выполнен
Ответ сервера:
Р¤Р°Р№Р» РЅРµ СЏРІР»СЏРµС‚СЃСЏ СЃС‚Р°РЅРґР°СЂС‚РѕРј XML, РїРѕРґСЂРѕР±РЅРѕСЃС‚Рё РІ Р¶СѓСЂРЅР°Р»Рµ

20.06.2017 08:23:29 Начало сеанса
20.06.2017 08:23:29 Цикл 1
20.06.2017 08:23:29    Обработка C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\1cbitrix
20.06.2017 08:40:20       НЕ ВЫГРУЖЕНО!!!
20.06.2017 08:40:20 Цикл 2
20.06.2017 08:40:20 Завершение сеанса

Выгрузка товаров завершена с ошибками!!!

В чем может быть проблема? Подскажите пожалуйста, т.к. перепробовали уже все что можно, но баг не лечится. Идет связка Сервер свой на котором 1С - хостинг.

Вот файлы импорта - [клац](http://dropmefiles.com/LoP7X)

Comment: я вносил ряд изменений в свой ответ. Вы могли пропустить какую-то информацию, если читали более раннюю редакцию. На данный момент не вижу возможности ничего больше добавить и предлагаю ознакомиться с последней версией ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"кракозябры", написанные в ответе сервера, переводятся на русский как: ***"Файл не является стандартом XML, подробности в журнале"***.

Происходит последнее, потому что ответ выдаётся в одной кодировки(Windows-1251), при этом в ответе указана другая.

---

Из ответа следует, что нарушена структура XML-документа.
Последнее зачастую может происходить из-за наличия в выгружаемых данных неэкранированных управляющих символов, причём скорее всего в тех местах, которые изначально не подразумевали наличия разметки.

Также необходимо проверить журнал на сервере, о котором говорится в ответе.
Там скорее всего будет указано, вплоть до номера строки и смещения вправо, место в котором произошла ошибка и по идущему выше контенту можно будет составить точное мнение: почему именно данный документ не прошел проверку.

---

Как я уже написал выше : скорее всего это неэкранированные теги и упраяляющие символы в выгружаемом содержимом.

Исправить на стороне 1С это крайне проблематично без 1С-программиста.

На стороне сайта это можно решить экранированием данных перед сохранением в БД и последующим преобразованием обратно в специальные символы при выводе на сайте.

**экранирование:**

```
htmlspecialchars($content);
```

**преобразование html-сущностей обратно в специальные символы:**

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($data);
```

Но данный способ является бесполезным, если первоисточником данных является 1С.

И третий способ:

**Убрать вручную вёрстку из проблемного содержимого в 1С.**

Вполне возможно, что на каком-то поле товара ставится галочка по типу содержимого текста (текст/html) и в зависимости от этого 1С экранирует данное поле перед выгрузкой или пропускает его.
И в каком-то конкретном случае оно не соответствует указанному значению(стоит галочка под пунктом "текст", но при этом поле содержимое содержит разметку).

---

Другой, проблемой может являться несоответствие xml-документа [CML2](http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/90/92.htm) формату, которым пользуется 1С для обмена с сайтом.
Но такая проблема, по-моему мнению может возникнуть только при кастомизированной выгрузке со стороны 1С.
При работе  модуля, предоставленного 1С, такой проблемы, по моему мнению, наблюдаться не должно.

[Стандарт CommerceML2](http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/90/92.htm)

---

*Если я оказался не прав в своём предположении, то просьба привести содержимое журнала к вопросу.*

Comment: Приложил в первом посте файлы импорта.

Comment: @Zvezd , файлы я видел, скачал, проверил валидность - они валидные(на этих конкретно файлах выгрузка завершилась с ошибкой?). Сейчас пытаюсь найти проблему, но это займёт чуть больше времени. Оставайтесь на связи, когда найду решение, обязательно его приложу сюда!

Comment: @Zvezd , и в поиске проблемы очень может помочь журнал. Он с большой вероятносьтю ускорит в разы поиск проблемы.Буду очень благодарен, если вы его приложите

Comment: Вот ссылка на журнал - http://dropmefiles.com/54JYB

Comment: @Zvezd, к сожалению это не тот журнал. Ошибка произошла при разборе xml на стороне сайта, соответственно журнал должен быть на стороне opencart'a.

Comment: К сожалению не сохранились логи на стороне opencart'a (